# I want a random homepage (from a predefined list) to show up when I click a link

Tags: javascript, html, random

I want a random homepage (from a predefined list) to show up when I click a link. And really this is Two questions so question one, is it possible? If yes then how?

What if the file are in different folders?
Would the code then look like this?

```
var arrPages = [   'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/feyra/feyra.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/rayne/rayne.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/adrienna/adrienna.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/averya/aveyra.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/demaen/demaen.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/phoenyx/phoenyx.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/raven/raven.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/trysten/trysten.html', 'http://neo.graceland.edu/~rmthomas/gothyc%20cafe/xiandre/xiandre.html'];
    document.getElementById('13').onclick = function () {
        var randUrl = arrPages[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrPages.length)];
        // Redirect/popup/new tab
        window.open(randUrl,'test');
    }
```

Comment: If you have to click a link... is that really a "home page"?

Comment: Do you want to have a single link send people to a randomly selected url or do you want a single url to display randomised content?

Comment: Chris, well yes and no i am building a web site for a class and i have to have a "homepage" but really it is an introduction page and the other pages are really there own sites but are interlinking and i am probably not explaining this right but i figured i ask to see if it was possible. and peter i'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// A predefined list of pages
        var arrPages =
            [
                'http://google.com',
                'http://yahoo.com',
                'http://xtra.co.nz',
                'http://asdf.com'
            ];

        // Get the element
        var aLink = document.getElementById('aLink');

        // Bind the click event of aLink
        aLink.onclick = function () {

            // Get an integer that'll determine the index of arrPages to access
            var randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrPages.length);

            // Get the element with an index of randomInt
            var randUrl = arrPages[randomInt];

            // Here you can do whatever you like with randUrl, in this case 
            //  we'll open a new window that'll point to randUrl
            //   e.g. http://xtra.co.nz
            window.open(randUrl, 'test');
        }
```

For an explanation of the functions used to set `randomInt`
see [Explain Math.floor(Math.random())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571010/explain-math-floormath-random)

Comment: i'm not quite sure how this works i think i'm missing something. Can you explain it in a little more detail please? thank you

Comment: what this does, is, creates a list of possible page links in an aray.  Then it sets the onclick of the link on the document to a function.  That function then sets randUrl to a random URL.  Math.floor(Math.random() * arrPages.length) creates the random integer that represents the index in the array.

Comment: OK, so how would i shift the code if i had different folders for the files?

Comment: in sted of  this :aLink.onclick = function () can't you use this?: function myFunction () { alert('hi');

Comment: yes, you can create a function and then assign that function to the click handler of aLink